# How to design the interface / abstract class here (OOP design)

Tags: java, oop, java-7

I have a abstract class and some classes extend the abstract class. Now i wanted to do some preprocessing before every functions present in the child classes (*for example the functions are nothing but fetching entities from DB, so before even going for DB just check the entities in the cache if the entities are present in the cache then return else call to `call()`  or `call(final Set<String> args)` fetch the entities store it in cache and return*). So i introduced an interface e.g.

```
interface PQRCallable <K> {
    K call();
    Set<K> call(final Set<String> args);
}
```

Inside the `call` function the subclass functions writes the logic to fetch the entities from DB. Now every function in the subclasses call either of the two common functions present in the abstract class i.e. `doProcessing(String k, ..., PQRCallable pQRCallable)` `doProcessing(Set<k>, ..., PQRCallable pQRCallable)` with a `PQRCallable` so that if the preprocessing will face any issue it would fall back to `call()` or `call(final Set<String> args)`.

My problem here is that now every functions inside the subclasses will need to implement both the functions. And `doProcessing(Set<k>, ..., PQRCallable pQRCallable)` will always call `Set<K> call(final Set<String> args);` and  `doProcessing(String k, ..., PQRCallable pQRCallable)` will always call `K call();`. Hence actually the subclass will just implement one function and for other function they should just throw some exception like `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Do anybody can suggest me a better approach for this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you make the methods `call()` and `call(Set<String>)` in the interface `default` methods?

Comment: can you provide what you have done or your codes :) TIA

Comment: you can implement this interface into your abstract class and you can override both function in abstract class so it will be applicable for all. no need to implement in all the sub classes.

Comment: @ChthonicProject thats a nice option but i am using java 7.

Comment: Then, as Prashant has stated, you should have an abstract class implementing the interface. All other classes could extend that abstract class.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. Do you want to ensure that every method call to a subclass is first forwarded to a specific method in the abstract class? If so do your subclasses have a common interface or do have completely different methods? Why should your subclasses implement the interface. I dont understand who is calling whom in your example. Can you provide some additional code?

Comment: I suggest wrapping your doProcessing and use startegy pattern

Comment: @Hichamov could you please add an example here. That would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the pattern [decorator](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern) can help you to handle that.

*Sorry the link is in C# but there is a nice UML schema!*

Comment: I like where you're going with this. Though IMO [Template Method](http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern) is a better fit for this problem.

Comment: This certainly could be a solution either. I like your username!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the doProcessing method :

```
doProcessing(String k, ...){
    this.pQRCallable.call();
    //Your processing logic
    //It could be useful to catch the UnsupportedOperationException
}

doProcessing(Set<K> k, ...){
    this.pQRCallable.call(args);//you didn't specify how you are getting the args
    //Your processing logic
}
```

You can see that the `pQRCallable` is now a field in your abstract class, and you could set it at runtime via utility class or using constructor of the concrete subclasses.

Sub-classes won't have to implement your interface and at runtime you'll be sure that you are setting the right PQRCallable (the one implementing your desired call)

Comment: More on strategy pattern [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your DB methods using Dynamic Proxies. In your Invocation Handler you could check whether the requested objects are in the cache already. Only if they are not in your cache you could forward the call to your actual DB accessing object. 
For example code check out: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a mature data access framework with caching, such as [Hibernate second-level cache](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm).

Failing that, your situation fits best into the [GoF Template Method](http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern) pattern. Pay particular attention to the [real world example for DataAccessObject](http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern#rea).